# exclude a project from maven parallelism build

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am having a project structure

```
ProjectTest
     - A
     - B
        - B1
            - B12
     - C
        - C1
     - D
```

Here D is the project which we are packaging source artifacts which is not having any dependency section.
When i am try execute without threading configuration it works as expected. When i try to execute it threads it fails at D because D and other projects executed in parallel fashion.
Is there any property or configuration to make the project to executed at last ie) remove it from parallel execution.

ie) other projects should be executed in parallel after that D should start the execution.

I am using maven version 3.

Comment: You are trying to package the source artifacts via maven-sources-plugin? Why do you have a separate module D for that?

Comment: yes. maven-sources-plugin will create a source artifacts in their respective modules. Publishing to central repository will be ok with maven-sources-plugin. We are trying to provide it as a complete package with all the source files. That why we placed an assembly package by placing assembly.xml.

Comment: I wouldn't try to go different way just go the convention it's easier...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Define dependencies from D to all modules that should run before D.

Comment: @Thanks Fabian. But D doesn't have any dependencies and D has to start at last so i have to place the other artifacts as the dependencies in D with scope provided?

Comment: This would be one sensible approach.

Comment: Is there any flags or properties to mark in pom.xml to make it clean with the normal maven build because i feel that the above approaches are kind of workaround. Because if i have huge number of  artifacts.